# Upgraded Symfony 4.4 to 5.4 getting error "Cannot autowire service"

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I recently upgraded to Symfony 5.4.*

Here is the error I am facing:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\V1\OrderPaymentController":
> argument "$mailer" of method "__construct()" references interface
> "App\Repository\MailingRepositoryInterface" but no such service
> exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

This error is coming when I am running the installation just after the upgrade.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. As it stands, your question is rather unclear. How or where are you receiving that error? On start-up, or are you running some codes/program that results in this error? Can you please [edit] your post to clarify?

Comment: @Adriaan Thank you. I am new to stack overflow. Can I request you to tell me what I should include more in this question?

Comment: You are trying to inject a repository interface which is a bit unusual in Symfony.  Assuming that you can run `bin/console debug:container` then you might verify the interface service does not exist.  It's possible you may need to explicitly create the interface alias.  Depends on what your config/services.yaml looks. like. You might consider updating your question with the relevant portion of services.yaml.